# Is it okay for tight loops to make calls to other files?

Tags: python

I'm wondering whether it is bad practice for a loop to repeatedly make calls to other files in python, or does python handle this better than I'm thinking?

I have a package that looks like:

```
__init__.py
main.py
utils.py
```

main.py

```
import utils

def main_loop():
    urls = [list_with_many_strings]
    for url in urls:
        data = utils.get_data(url)
        print(data)
```

utils.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_data(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
    data = soup.find(id='spam')
    return data
```

My question is whether it is wrong to make calls to other files like this in general. Does python have to reference utils.py with each iteration through the loop? Or does it just need to cache the get_data() function a single time?

This is a pretty basic example, but I am running into memory errors with functions that make calls to other files repeatedly, and I'm wondering if this is the reason why.

Comment: The `import` statement is where the content of that file is loaded. You don't need to worry about it after that.

Comment: Are you running into memory errors with *this* code?

Comment: @Blorgbeard No, this is just an example to illustrate the concept.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I guess I want to know whether the 'import requests' line is processed in any way with each iteration of main_loop(). Or does get_data() get pulled into main.py while it is running?

Comment: Well, a call to an imported function is not going to cause memory errors by itself. The problem must be something else. Can you construct a [mre] that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your concerns are, but this is normal practice, if that makes you feel better. Note, it is important to understand, *functions aren't located in the .py file, source code is*. Once the source code has been executed, the function exists in the memory of the python process.

Comment: @Joseph no, the `import requests` gets run exactly once.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This answers a lot of my questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Python caches the contents of a module when you `import` it the first time. The interpreter runs the module's code (including the definitions of classes and functions), and keeps the global namespace around for you to access later. So it's not excessively costly to keep looking up a function or variable from another module. It is pretty much like looking up a global variable in the current module.

That's not to say that it's free, however. Looking up an attribute or global variable needs to do some dictionary lookups, and that could theoretically be the slowest part of some high performance code. In such a case, you might want to cache the lookup in a local variable (which can be accessed very quickly).

```
def example(data):
    lookup = foo.bar  # cache an attribute lookup in a local variable

    for x in data:
        do_something(lookup, x)  # use local variable rather than do_something(foo.bar, x)
```

This is rarely necessary though, as usually the other parts of the code (e.g. the iteration over `data` or the body of `do_something`) will take so much time that the cost of a repeated attribute lookup would get lost in the noise if you left it in. In your example code, the web request and HTML parsing will be orders of magnitude slower than looking up the functions, so you probably shouldn't worry about it at all.